# Implement a mask in React Native

Tags: react-native

Seems simple, but couldn't imagine the implementation. How do we paint everything (e.g. dark blue with 0.5 alpha in the given picture) except the insides of the circle?

[image: dog]

[image: dog]

Comment: The original image is already with dark blue or u written some code to have the dark blue?

Comment: Code is written for it to be dark blue to highlight the problem that there's no straightforward way to paint the non-dark blue spots outside the circle.

Comment: Perhaps you should then provide the code for the masking part